# Instruments and Shark

Tags: ios, debugging, testing, cocos2d-iphone

I've finally reached the end of app creation.
I know that Instruments and Shark can be used to test for memory leaks and other such "bad stuff" in your apps. Unfortunately I can't find any good tutorials on how to use these tools.
Especially for Shark, how should I go about using these tools?
Additionally, are there any other similar tools that may be more powerful or easy to use? Thanks you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to find memory leaks and other problems is to use static analysis. If you're using Xcode, there's an integrated tool that's located in Product->Analyze.

Answer (score 3):

Shark is no longer really used, use the Time Profiler instrument instead.

Currently your best bet is reading through the Apple documentation on Instruments.